# How to run micro services using docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, cassandra, docker-compose, microservices

Am newbie to Spring boot. I need to create micro services and need to run by docker. I have attached my project structure here. Problem which is every time i need to up the micro services manually. For example am having 4 micro services and i just up this services manually. But all micro services should be started itself when deploying into docker. How to achieve this. [image: Project Structure]

Also am using Cassandra database.

Comment: An old post of mine, [Microservices using Spring Boot, Jersey, Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html) goes through that exercise, building the jar artifacts, builds and deploys Docker image to Docker hub and starts a Docker container of such image. I would suggest though to split each service to its own scm repo, that's the recommendation according to the [12 Factor app](https://12factor.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it is the one i used: 
First say to the spring boot maven plugin to create an executable jar :

```
<configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
</configuration>
```

After that you can add your application as a service in `init.d` and make it start when the container starts. 
You can find a better explaination here : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the numerous tutorials that exists for spring boot and dockerizing this application.

[Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) is one which explains every step that is necessary

1. Build Application as Jar File
2. Create your docker image with Dockerfile
   In this dockerfile you create an environment like you would have a new setup linux server and you define what you need for software to run your application: like java. Have a look at existing images like [anapsix/alpine-java](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/alpine-java/).
3. Now think of what you need to do to start your app in this environment: java -jar --some-options -location-of-your-jar.jar
4. Make sure to be able to reach your app by exposing the docker port so that you can see that is runs.

As I sad if these instruction is not helpful for you, then please read tutorials for docker and dockerizing spring boot applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should use docker-compose. Best way to manage releases/versions and builds is to make own repository for dedicated docker images(nexus is an example).

In docker-compose you can describe all your infrastructure, create services, network, connecting services to communicate other services, so I think you should go this way to create nice developmnet and production build flow for your microservice application

For cassandra and other  known services you can find prefered images on `https://hub.docker.com`.

In each microservice you should have Dockerfile, then in main directory of your solution you can create `docker-compose.yml` file with services definitions.

You can build your microservices in docker container too. Read more about "Java application build flow with docker" in google.

All about docker compose you can find here: `https://docs.docker.com/compose/`

All about docker swarm you can find here: `https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/`